# Some Aptana features missing when mixing PHP and HTML in the same file

Tags: php, html, aptana, aptana3

I've been using Aptana Studio 3 for the last weeks as a replacement for Dreamweaver and I'm really liking it.

I'm only having some problems when I mix HTML and PHP in the same *.php file.

First thing I found was that the HTML code-folding feature in gone with .php extension files. In this thread they say it should be solved in latest versions but not in my case: https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/suggestions/230-mixed-html-php-files

In my case the only way to bring it back is writing the first html line like this:

```
<?php echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">';?>
```

This way it all works perfectly but I think there should be another way to do it.

Second missing feature:

If I open a .css file in a proyect, it will suggest any existing id or class in the current proyect just by typing . or #. This is great but only suggests id's or classes in *.HTML files. It just doesn't read the PHP files. This is a real problem for me as most of my files are *.php and this feature would save me lots of time.

Again, I found a "solution" for this but it's really nasty and not appropiate at all: Every now and then I save .php files as .html in a folder called "bin" just to have all my id's and classes available in my .CSS files. Isn't there another way to solve it?

Thanks a lot in advance.